# Proving that norm function is continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $B:=\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the function $f:B\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=\|x\|$. I want to prove that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $B$. One way is to use single-variable calculus and find the general partial derivative of $f$ on $B$ explicitly and then observe that it is continuous on $B$. But I decided to use the definition of the directional derivative and use $f^2(x)=\|x\|^2$ instead. This gives that $\partial_i f(x)=2x_i$ for $1\le i \le n$.

But does the fact that $f^2$ has a continuous partial derivative also imply that $f$ has it? The issue is that for $x=\vec{0}$, we can't observe the fact that $f$ has no continuous partial derivative at this point, but $f^2$ does have one.

I'd appreciate if someone could please clarify this matter for me.

Comment: This follows from the chain rule. If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f:U \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is continuously differentiable, then since $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ we must have $\sqrt{f}$ also continuously differentiable.

Comment: @AlexZorn This doesn't prove that the norm function is continuously differentiable at 0, which it is.

Comment: @jwg I don't think it is, the partial derivatives don't even exist at 0, since $||\mathbf{0} + h\mathbf{e}_i|| = |h|$, where $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the $i$th unit vector.

Comment: @AlexZorn You are right, don't know why I said this.

Comment: I think partial derivatives do exist at $0$, and they should be equal to $1$. But they are not continuous there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compositions of $C^\infty$ functions are $C^\infty.$ So if $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, $g:U \to (0,\infty),$ and $g\in C^\infty(U),$ then $g^{1/2}\in C^\infty(U).$ This is because $t\to t^{1/2}$ is in $C^\infty((0,\infty)),$ which implies $g^{1/2}$ is the composition of two $C^\infty$ functions. For your particular case we would take $g(x) = |x|^2, U = \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}.$

Answer (score 4):

Let $C^1$ denote "continuously differentiable."

The sum or product of any finite set of $C^1$ functions from $\mathbb R^n$ \ $\{0\}$  to $\mathbb R$  is also  $C^1.$

If $f:\mathbb R^n$ \  $\{0\}\to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$ and the image of $f$ is $\mathbb R^+$, and if $g:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ is  $C^1$ then the composite  function $gf$  is $C^1.$

For  any fixed $\in \{1,...,n\}$ and for $x=(x_1,...x_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ \ $\{0\}$ let $P_j(x)=x_j.$

All you have to do is prove that each $P_j$ is $C^1$.

Then each product $f_j(x)=P_j(x)\cdot P_j(x) =x_j^2$ is $C^1.$

Then the sum  $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nf_j(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2$ is $C^1.$

Now $g(y)=\sqrt y\;$ is $C^1$ from $\mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R.$ Therefore $\|x\|=g(f(x))$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb R^n$ \ $ \{0\}.$

Comment: Question from a nonmathematician regarding notation: $C^1$ means "continuously differentiable (as a real-valued function) *once*"? So, a [raised cosine](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Raised-cosine_filter.svg/585px-Raised-cosine_filter.svg.png) would belong to $C^2$ but not to $C^3$? If I understand correctly, the discussion regards only real analysis and real-valued differentiability.

Comment: @thb. The usual convention is that a $C^n$ function has a continuous $n$-th derivative. In this context that means that $\nabla (f)$ is continuous.

Comment: @thb. The convention is that $f$ is $C^n$ iff $f$ has a continuous $n$-th derivative. In the context of the Q , "$f$ is $C^1$" means that $\nabla (f)$ is continuous.... I can't tell from the picture in your link what a raised cosine is. I never heard of it.

Comment: The raised cosine need not interest you, but for information, without too much detail, a typical raised cosine is $f(t) = (1+\cos\pi t)/2$ over the domain $t\in [-1, 1]$, outside of which domain $f(t)=0$. It is a nonanalytic but real-differentiable function an engineer can use in place of the analytic Gaussian pulse (that is, the Gaussian PDF) when the engineer wishes to restrict the pulse's period of activity. Somewhere in the comms channel over which you and I are now communicating, our messages are probably embodied in raised-cosine pulses.

Comment: I appreciate your reply more than you know. I hold a master's degree in engineering but except linear algebra my coursework was too light in math-department mathematics. I had one semester of complex analysis; zero semesters of real analysis; zero semesters of topology, etc. I was never going to earn a mathematics degree like you, so that's all right; but the result is that I cannot read much of the notation on this site. By the kind advice of persons like you I am trying to learn better notation. Thanks.

Comment: @thb.  One convention on this site is that $\mathbb N$ is the set of positive integers, although many people (including me) prefer $\mathbb Z^+$ for the positive integers and would prefer that $0$ belongs to $\mathbb N$. You may also see $]a,b[$ for $(a,b)=\{x: a<x<b\}$ which is not a bad idea because $(a,b)$ has other meanings  (including an ordered pair).

Answer (score 3):

The norm is Lipschitz with rank 1 hence is differentiable almost everywhere (this is not trivial to prove).

However, in general a norm is not differentiable at every $x \neq 0$.

For example, $f(x) = \|x\|_\infty = \max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)$ is not differentiable whenever there are two or more indices for which the $\max$ is attained.